# Создать XML через DOM и провалидировать его

Tags: java

У меня есть xml документ:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transports transportid="1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="transport.xsd">
    <transport>
        <marka>Mersedes</marka>
        <weight>100</weight>
        <gos_number>k500u</gos_number>
    </transport>
    <firstname>Mikhail</firstname>
    <surname>Semenov</surname>   
</transports>
```

И xsd схема к нему для проверки на валидность:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="transports">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="transport">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="marka" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="gos_number" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="transportidid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Мне необходимо через java DOM создать точно такой же xml документ и программно провалидировать его. Подскажите как правильно сделать, я в этом новичок поэтому не знаю как правильно написать код для решения такой задачи. Все откликнувшимся заранее спасибо.

Нашел решение здесь
[ссылка 1](https://javadevblog.com/kak-sozdat-xml-fajl-na-java-ispol-zuem-dom-parser.html)

Но здесь работа с простыми типами данных, а у меня тег transport сложный тип.

По валидации нашел решение здесь[ссылка 2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/)

но в листинге 1 на строке 25, такая строчка кода
Source source = new StreamSource(args[0]);
я не понимаю что за тип данных Source и что-нужно сделать чтобы передать ему именно уже готовый файл xml.

Answer (score 0):

Для формирования XML-файла из java кода полезная информация тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd

Для валидации использовал библиотеку xmlunit

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

private boolean validateXmlAgainstXsd(InputStream xmlFileStream) {
    String xsdSchema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(XSD_FILE_NAME_URI)));
    Validator validator = Validator.forLanguage(Languages.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    validator.setSchemaSource(Input.fromString(xsdSchema).build());
    ValidationResult r = validator.validateInstance(Input.fromStream(xmlFileStream).build());

    if(r.getProblems().isEmpty()) {
       return true;        
    }

    Iterator<ValidationProblem> probs = r.getProblems().iterator();
    while (probs.hasNext()) {
       LOG.error(probs.next().toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```